# Is it possbile to test for expected errors when the testee exits with failure using TAP within Perl?

Tags: perl, testing, tap

Suppose you're running some unit tests and you want to see if the method ( or script or function or whatever) you're testing fails as it should. How do you setup such a test?  I'm hoping for something like this:

```
ok( $obj->method($my, $bad, $params) == DEATH, 'method dies as expected');
```

although I don't see how it would work since `method` `die`s when passed bad parameters and the test script stops.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Test::Exception](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aException)?  `dies_ok` should do what you want.  Eg:

```
# Check that something died - we do not care why
dies_ok { $foo->method } 'expecting to die';
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Test::Fatal](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aFatal) rather than [Test::Exception](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aException).

Test::Exception has been around for a long time, so a lot of existing test suites use it, but Test::Fatal is easier to learn.  Test::Fatal exports only 1 function: `exception`.  This runs the associated code and returns the exception that it threw, or `undef` if it ran without error.  You then test that return value using any of the normal [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore) functions like `is`, `isnt`, `like`, or `isa_ok`.

Test::Exception requires you to learn its own testing functions like `throws_ok` and `dies_ok`, and remember that you don't put a comma between the code and the test name.

So, your example would be:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Fatal;

my $obj = ...;

isnt(exception { $obj->method($my, $bad, $params) },
     undef, 'method dies as expected');
```

Or you could use `like` to match the expected error message, or `isa_ok` to test if it threw the correct class of exception object.

Test::Fatal just gives you more flexibility with less learning curve than Test::Exception.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to use a module to do this.  You can just wrap the call that you expect to fail in an `eval` block like so:

```
ok !eval {$obj->method($my, $bad, $params); 1}, 'method dies as expected';
```

If all goes well in the `eval`, it will return the last statement executed, which is `1` in this case.  if it fails, `eval` will return `undef`.  This is the opposite of what `ok` wants, so `!` to flip the values.

You can then follow that line with a check of the actual exception message if you want:

```
like $@, qr/invalid argument/, 'method died with invalid argument';
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there are edge cases that can be tricky to get right, and the code that handles them correctly is awkward to repeat in your tests.  See [rjbs's explanation of Test::Fatal](http://advent.rjbs.manxome.org/2010/2010-12-07.html).

Comment: @cjm => There are NO edge cases that could cause the `ok` line to fail.  The only corner case that I can think of here is if there is an `eval` in a `DESTROY` that clobbers the error string.  And that will only make the `like` test fail.  But that is arguably then catching a bug which should be fixed.  None of the examples in Test::Fatal or Text::Exception seem to make this any easier, they just hide `!eval{...; 1}` behind a function call.  Modules are good, but adding a dependency just to wrap such a simple construct has dubious value.

Comment: There's also the possibility that Test::More (or some other testing library) will do an `eval` and clobber `$@` before you look at it.