# Planning for deaths in perl tests

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

Is there a way to write tests for Perl calls that you expect to die? I'd like to verify that certain calls will die with poorly formatted inputs.

```
sub routine_a {
   my $arg = shift;
   die if $arg eq 'FOO';
   print "routine_a: $arg\n";
}
sub routine_b {
   my $arg = shift;
   die if $arg eq 'BAR';
   print "routine_b: $arg\n";
}

sub test_all {
   assert( routine_a("blah") );
   assert( routine_b("blab") );
   assert_death( routine_a("FOO") );
   assert_death( routine_b("BAR") );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Test::Exception](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aException):

```
use Test::Exception;
dies_ok { $foo->method } 'expecting to die';
```

Comment: I find [Test::Fatal](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aFatal) to be easier to use than Test::Exception, as I said in [my answer to an earlier question on the same subject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4522172/8355).

Answer (score 5):

You wrap the test in an `eval { ... }` block and check whether `$@` was set.

```
eval { test_thats_supposed_to_fail() };
ok( $@ , "test failed like it was supposed to" );
```

Comment: Preferably your test should die with an expected message, so that you can check the value of $@ rather than just testing its existence.